# Jupyter Lab - Use input() while interacting with a ipywidget and for it to execute observe method and thus update the widget

Tags: python, multithreading, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

In jupyterlab, I'm using a ipywidget consisting of nested Tab widgets with a HTML widget for each leaf Tab children. I was wondering is it possible to interact with this ipywidget while waiting for input using input() . I'm loading strings into the HTML widget when Tab.selected_index changes using observe() because jupyterlab complains about too many operations or something like that but because of input blocking nothing is happening.

So in pseudocode

1. I create the widget `Tab_5` a Tab Widget which for each Tab has another Tab Widget associated with it. Eg Queries have associated tabs 1-10, 11-20 are top level tabs and Tabs 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 are nested under Tab 1 - 10 etc
2. create `def on_value_change(change)`

```
        if len(Tab_5.children[Tab_5.selected_index].children[Tab_5.children[Tab_5.selected_index].selected_index].value) == 0:
            index = 10 * Tab_5.selected_index + Tab_5.children[Tab_5.selected_index].selected_index
            Tab_5.children[Tab_5.selected_index].children[Tab_5.children[Tab_5.selected_index].selected_index].value = "<div style ='line-height: normal;'>"+ descList[index] + "<br><br>"+ str(queryStrings[index]) + "<br><br>" + str(responses[index]) + "</div>"
```

3. assign it to the children widgets using `Tab_5.children[i].observe(on_value_change, names='selected_index')`, `Tab_5.observe(on_value_change, names='selected_index')`

So I looked at https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Asynchronous.html and didn't really understand it and tried doing stuff with the last example.

Basically I'm running some queries using an API and I want to see my past queries in the tabbed interface before choosing to continuing on with future queries with the same parameters apart from one which is incremented. But at the moment, the tabbed widget is not updating while waiting for input.

So previously I generated some Markdown as output but it become really slow. I also at one stage used

```
    from IPython.core.getipython import get_ipython
    shell = get_ipython()
    payload = dict(
        source='set_next_input',
        text=contents,
        replace=False,
    )
    shell.payload_manager.write_payload(payload, single = False)
    
create_new_cell("".join(output))
```

which created a new code cell which needed to be manually turned into a Markdown cell. (You can programmatically create a cell in Jupyter Notebook but not Jupyter Lab)

So do I need to do something with threads or asyncio? Is this possible or can I accomplish this in a better way by having a widget for the input?

Any suggestions?

Comment: You either need to commit to using current ipywidgets system in JupyterLab or use the classic Jupyter Notebook interface. Not clear why you are bringing up using `input()` or `shell.payload_manager.write_payload(payload, single = False)` , but your title begins 'JupyterLab'?  (`input()` isn;t compatile with ipwidgets.) And then suddenly you are taking about ayncio? Your post is biting off a lot. It would probably be easier to find examples closer to what you want & then build if you are going to commit to working in JuyterLab. Have you looked at [the Voila Gallery](https://voila-gallery.org/)?

Comment: Also [the Jupyter Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/) is more suitable for discussions & advice seeking of this sort than StackOverflow.

Comment: Um, I added that level of detail because sometimes I see on stack overflow posts - that people say you should say what you are trying to do rather than a question regarding code without context (I guess listing the history of what I was doing in the past isn't the same thing though).  Asyncio was mentioned in the earlier link in ipywidgets.